# WP7 Push Notification - Power Management

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

Microsoft documentation says that if the battery power of the device is critically low then the app will not receive push notifications. If the battery power is low but not critically low then the app will receive only Raw notifications.

In these two cases an ErrorOccurred event is received, do we have to show an error message to the user explaining the what has happened. Is it fine displaying an error message when the battery level is low?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not receiving messages on the phone, how will the app know to inform the user. Even if it isn't running.

When restarting the app you shoudl always check (and if necessary re-establish) channels.
If it's appropriate to let the user know there was a problem and it has now been fixed. And/or that previous notifications failed then you should do so.